# Closing wrapped resources in Java

Tags: java, io

Consider the typical code:

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("42.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
} finally {
        //??
}
```

Should `close` in the `finally` clause be called for both or them or is it sufficient to `close` only one reader (if so, then which one?).

I would think that it should be sufficient to close only the most external wrapper, because with the following code that utilises try with resources only `br` will be closed:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("42.txt"))) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outermost one. It will then call `close()` on the wrapped stream etc. if it's implemented correctly (which is certainly true for JDK classes).